# GLSL fragment shader weird if-else behaviour giving compiler error

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm having a weird error when compiling a fragment shader. The error log says:

```
Error in Shader compilation: 0(226) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting "::" at token ","
```

The context is that I'm calculating scene lights with the fragment shader, and my idea was that, if there are no lights, the output color of the object has to be its ambient color, else, has to be black to perform light calculations (which will take into account the ambient color).

So, the ambient color is a vec4 passed through a uniform and I have also 3 int uniforms to pass the quantity of directional, spot and point lights. When I try to execute the next code:

```
vec4 colorOutput = vec4(vec3(0.0), 1.0);
if((u_CurrentSPLights + u_CurrentDirLights + u_CurrentPointLights) > 0)
    colorOutput = u_AmbientColor;
```

It gives the mentioned compiling error. However, if I delete that if statement and the "colorOutput = u_AmbientColor" line, and keep all the other shader code as it is, it compiles and work as expected.

I've been looking into this for some time but I still don't understand why a thing as simple as an if statement (that It doesn't seem to be wrong syntactically) is producing that compile error.

**Update:** Even if I comment the 2 lines after the "vec4 colorOutput = ..." line, it still crash, but if I delete them, it works... This is very confusing. This probably has to do with the next lines, which are 3 for loops running through the lights to calculate their effects, 3 loops like the next:

```
for(int i = 0; i < u_CurrentDirLights; ++i)
        colorOutput += CalculateDirectionalLight(DirLightsArray[i], normalVec, viewDirection, !u_TextureEmpty);
```

Comment: We'll have to see more code. For example, it's not at all clear what the types of the things involved up there are. Ideally, provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)…

Comment: How are you compiling the shader? The fact that it is expecting `::` is a bit weird as a GLSL compiler should never expect that token as far as I am aware.

Comment: You really need to provide the whole shader for us to have a chance of helping with this kind of error.